# How to get Ubuntu 20.04 to autoconnect to VPN upon starting VM

Tags: login, network-manager, vpn, 20.04, hyper-v

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 in Hyper-V. I have my Wired connection set to auto connect to my university VPN. It works no problem when I click connect. However, it is the fact I have to click connect that bothers me. When I start up, for some reason it doesn't automatically start my wired connection with VPN, I have to manually click to start it. It also causes stuff like Livepatch to bug out because I don't have internet when I start up. Any way to force it to turn my wired connection and hence VPN on when I start the VM/log in to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Run `nm-connection-editor` to edit the connection settings of your Guest network interface.

It exposes several options that are usually hidden, including VPN autoconnection.

Comment: That is where I added the automatic connection to vpn. Connect automatically is already ticked. The priority is -999, would changing that help?